# Facebook SDK v5 Error : Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

*Facebook SDK v5*

*Facebook Graph v2.4*

I get this error :

```
Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing.
```

Here is my code :

```
$facebookAppId = Configure::read(('Facebook.appId'));
$facebookAppSecret = Configure::read(('Facebook.appSecret'));

$this->fb = new Facebook(['app_id' => $facebookAppId,
                          'app_secret' => $facebookAppSecret,
                          'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
                          'default_access_token' => $facebookAppId.'|'.$facebookAppSecret]);

$helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

Do you have any solution ?
Thanks you.

Comment: Check if `$_GET['state']` exists and is not empty at that point. If not, check your routing/rewrite configuration, and see if it got lost in there somehow.

Comment: Thanks you for your quick reply but my `$_GET['state']` is not empty. 
I also check that my session is started. Does anyone has had this type of error ?

Comment: Is this any use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520593/facebook-php-sdk-5-api-2-4-cross-site-request-forgery-validation-failed-r/31542061?noredirect=1#comment51055949_31542061 or perhaps this? https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/issues/473 seems to have solved some similar issues for some users.

Comment: Can you add `session_start()` at the top of all your scripts, before calling any SDK method? Does that solve the issue?